Error of request on Qt C++ to WebAssembly
I'm trying to run a program which converts a currency into an other one by proceeding to a request with Qt (C++) thanks to the class QNetworkAccessManager.
I succeed normally when using GNU, however, I encounter a problem when I run on Web at the moment where I asking for the request.
I let you see the error just below :
Application exit (RuntimeError: Aborted(native code called abort()))

I tried to add some specific arguments to .pro file concerning QMake but it seems to crash again.
I also attempt by choosing either WebAssembly(multi-thread) and WebAssembly(single-thread) but the same thing appears.
If it's needed, I will provide an MRI example
Thanks in advance

If you made a debug build, you should get a stack trace if you check the Console tab in browser developer tools (opens with F12). Maybe that will give more information.

Are you sure that what you do is supported by QNetworkAccessManager? I don't have lots of experience with QT, but networking is very limited in WASM. You need code that explicitly supports the WASM networking which is a partial implementation of what is available in POSIX.
